# How to replace duplicate keys in string to array like with regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string receiving from a third-party

`{ messages: {\n something:'val' }\n messages: {\n something:'val2' }\n }\n`

I want to change this by regular expression to below string

`{ messages: [{\n something:'val' }\n , {\n something:'val2' }\n ] }\n`

### Simple version

`{ messages: {something:'val'}  messages: { something:'val2' } }`

to

`{ messages: [{something:'val'} , { something:'val2' } ] }`

### Update

This is part of my string so there are some more properties before and after like

`{ prop1: 'val1', { prop2: 'val2' ,  messages: {something:'val'}  messages: { something:'val2' } } }`

expected

`{ prop1: 'val1', { prop2: 'val2' ,  messages: [{something:'val'} , { something:'val2' } ] } }`

### Update

my real string is

`id: \"55b3a5c5-16e7-4ae6-91bc-7f08fb152dde-ee1dc704\"\nlang: \"en\"\nsession_id: \"6b1f9ba2-7c79-47bc-aadb-2c600b111836\"\ntimestamp: \"2019-09-04T17:13:43.374Z\"\nresult {\n  source: \"agent\"\n  resolved_query: \"welcome\"\n  action: \"customSettingsAnswer\"\n  score: 1.0\n  parameters {\n    fields {\n      key: \"key\"\n      value {\n        string_value: \"welcome\"\n      }\n    }\n    fields {\n      key: \"default\"\n      value {\n        string_value: \"Hello, you called condo bot. Your virtual concierge. How can I help you today?\"\n      }\n    }\n  }\n  metadata {\n    intent_id: \"040b9e41-d20e-4da8-9fff-d2c1f1f5812e\"\n    webhook_response_time: 4992\n    intent_name: \"Default Welcome Intent - custom\"\n    webhook_used: \"true\"\n    webhook_for_slot_filling_used: \"false\"\n    is_fallback_intent: \"false\"\n  }\n  fulfillment {\n    speech: \"Hello, you called condo bot. Your virtual concierge. How can I help you today?\"\n    messages {\n      lang: \"en\"\n      type {\n        number_value: 0.0\n      }\n      speech {\n        string_value: \"Text 1\"\n      }\n    }\n messages {\n      lang: \"en\"\n      type {\n        number_value: 0.0\n      }\n      speech {\n        string_value: \"Text 2\"\n      }\n    }\n } \n}\nstatus {\n  code: 200\n  error_type: \"success\"\n}\n`

p.s In my real string there are more inside of each message object, I just  removed them for simplicity in here

Comment: Get all the group 1s from `messages: ({[^}]+})`, joining them with commas, and then create the new string with `"{ messages: [" + group1WithCommas + "]}"`?

Comment: @Sweeper I just saw that. I never ceases to amaze me that third parties are still contriving their own data formatting.

Comment: @Sweeper seems good, but I am really bad at regex

Comment: @Sweeper it's funny that third-party is google dialogflow

Comment: @Sweeper so you are saying do the grouping by regex and do the rest in js? or all can be done in regex?

Comment: You should do part of it in JS. I don't think you can do it with a single regex replace.

Comment: It's funny that their [docs show JSON](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/quick/api#detect-intent-text-drest)...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I receive this from their logging into google stackdriver, and the format is not json, is somehow wierd

Comment: In your sample output I don't see any "replace duplicate keys" happening. What I see is just the inner objects inclosed inside a single array. Can you clarify your desired output?

Comment: @Addis `message` is duplicate and I want it to become only one and some changes  in the style to become like array

Answer (score 0):

Here a possible solution:

```js
var messages = "{ prop1: 'val1', { prop2: 'val2' ,  messages: {something:'val'}  messages: { something:'val2' } } }";
var result = [];

messages.split('messages:').map(
  message => {
  console.log(message)
    const val = message.match(/{\s*(.*):'(.*)'\s*}/)
    if (val) {
      result.push({[val[1]]: val[2]})
    }
  }
)
console.log({messages: result})
```

Comment: Sorry, you updated the question during I was writing response.

Comment: No worries, I saw your answer and after I updated my question ;)

Comment: Thanks, can we get rid of `something` because in my real string I have a complex object there is not like that all the time, the only thing I need to hard code is `messages`

Comment: please see my real string, I don't think split will be an option

Comment: Sorry, still the output is not correct, since there are other props to be returned as result  and at the console.log it's only messages

Comment: You boring me. Please ask correctly your question and don't change every 5mins.. In SO, I sometimes feel working for someone who don't care about other and just want fast response to their problem for free... sorry.

Comment: Sorry for that, I made it simple to be answered, my edit was adding my real string there. I know it's not free, if you take a look at my points you see how much I am contributing too, my unfortunate is my knowledge of regex is 0

Answer (score 0):

What I did is:

1. use regex and convert the string to look like JSON string format
   (`str1` in the code)
2. again use regex to split the string into separate object like strings(`str2` in my code). Here I could have just parsed the whole string(str1) but in doing so I would loose duplicate key objects, so I parsed the strings(str2) separately.
3. parse each string into object(`arr` in my code).
4. add these objects into a new object with values as arrays and if an object has duplicate keys just push the value inside the existing key.

.

```
let str = "{ messages: {something:'val'}  messages: { something:'val2' } }";
let reg = /[:}{a-zA-Z1-9]{1,}/g;

let str1 = str.replace(/\s/,'').match(reg).map(str => {
  if(/\w/.test(str)){
    let s = str.match(/\w{1,}/).toString();
    return str.replace(s, '"'+ s +'"');
  }
  else  
    return str;
});

let str2 = str1.toString().replace(/,{/g,'{').replace(/,}/g,'}').replace(/:,/g,':').replace(/{,/g,'{');

let arr = str2.replace('},','}},{').split(',').map(str => JSON.parse(str));

let obj = {};

for(o of arr){
  Object.keys(o).forEach(key => {
    if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
      obj[key] = [o[key]];
    else
      obj[key].push(o[key]);
  });
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution, it seems too restricted to my simple example, I am not sure if I can use it on my complex string